# Why must the vertices of a delta complex be ordered?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

We can compute the homology of nice spaces by putting either a delta complex or simplicial structure on that space and computing the homology of the associated chain complex. With a simplicial structure we are able to work more intuitively because the chain complex is made out of oriented simplexes but each set of vertices must correspond to at most one simplex. With delta complexes this condition on the vertices is removed but we are instead working with ordered simplexes which restricts our mode of computation.

I'm trying to understand why these tradeoffs don't change the homology of the associated chain complexes. Computations through simplicial complexes always seem to be computing honest geometric information but I can't say the same for computations with delta complexes and I would like to at least know why certain things I want to do with delta complexes (e.g. say a singular simplex $\sigma: \Delta^n \to X$ is negated when precomposed with a canonical orientation reversing homeomorphism $\Delta^n \to \Delta^n$ , but this is really singular homology) shouldn't work. I think what I'm really looking for is a proof showing that they are the same and which addresses these tradeoffs.